# Refactoring C#, unsure of error messages when converting to static method

Tags: c#, visual-web-developer

I'm a bit stuck with refactoring my code to make a method available to another page. I have the following code which is giving me trouble. Maybe there is a better angle to come at this from? Essentially I'm trying to make a function static so I can reuse the code but it's tripping me up.

```
public static Table BuildProjectTable(string CRNumber)
{
    LinkButton SelectLink = new LinkButton();
    SelectLink.ID = CRNumber + "," + ShipId + "," + StageId;
    ProgressStatus CurrentStatus = AAGlobal.GetProgressStatus(CRNumber, ShipId, StageId);
    SelectLink.Text = CurrentStatus.CurrentAssignee;
    SelectLink.BackColor = CurrentStatus.CurrentStatus;
    SelectLink.ForeColor = Color.White;
    BodyCells[CellCount].BackColor = CurrentStatus.CurrentStatus;
    BodyCells[CellCount].ForeColor = Color.White;

    // This fails because SelectLink_Click isn't static (I think)
    //
    SelectLink.Click += new EventHandler(SelectLink_Click);

    BodyCells[CellCount].Controls.Add(SelectLink);

    CellCount++;
}


// If I make this static (fixing above error), Session, Response and lstProcess
// all complain an object reference is required

public void SelectLink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton ClickedLink = (LinkButton)sender;
    string[] ClickRef = ClickedLink.ID.ToString().Split(',');

    Session["CR_NUMBER"] = ClickRef[0];
    Session["SHIP_ID"] = ClickRef[1];
    Session["STAGE_ID"] = ClickRef[2];
    Session["PROCESS_NAME"] = lstProcess.SelectedValue;

    Response.Redirect("~/EditStage.aspx");
}
```

Comment: What's the point? If you need to share that peace of code you have to pass all parameters...
(I do not think you should make your event handler static)

Comment: What do you mean pass all parameters? I am not used to the concept of handling events etc like this, I come from PHP where what I would have done is just generated the link manually and handled it using GET variables from the button press. I have to do postback stuff here and the only way I know to generate a link to do a postback is this way - is there a better way?

Comment: Simply do not make your methods static if they need to use elements in the page. Session, controls and stuffs (properties) like that aren't static. Image the page like an object where each element is a field/property. When ASP.NET serves a page it creates a new instance of that object, populates its properties and calls its methods (as needed). Static methods can be used if you need to improve performance A LITTLE BIT (but it's useless in a web application) and  usually you do not have to do it for "normal" methods like event handlers.

Comment: I see, because basically I came under the impression I needed to make the method static to access it from another page. I want a higher level view which nests the information normally you drill down into, but to use the method I was doing 'PageName.Method', which wouldn't work unless I made Method static. Is there another way that this can work without making the method static?

Comment: No. But make static only the part of your method that you **REALLY** need to share across pages (is it your purpose?) or pay the "penalty" to pass all the parameters it needs.

Comment: Okay got it. I think that wouldn't be a problem but the use of EventHandler for the hyperlink click event is confusing me. I could just have an exact duplicate of the event handler on every page that needs it but that was what I thought I would be eliminating by making it static and referring to it. Or would you pass in stuff like Session as an event argument?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8645/discussion-between-deed02392-and-adriano)

Comment: If you share some kind of logic for 2 or 3 pages you may consider to use a common base class for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the "lstProcess" ? Is it static ?

If it's not, your problem might come from that...

Also, assuming you are making asp.net, Session, Response, Cookies,.. are not static and depends on a Request. This explains why you don't have access to them..
Anyway, making an EventHandler static is not a good idea.

Maybe you should consider making a new static method that takes a Session and whatever you need in parameters and calling it from the EventHandler.

Comment: Maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree? Can you give me an example of how a new static method would take parameters to get around this? I use the event method so that when a user clicks on the link the site knows what values to set so it can build a new view based on that information.

Comment: It seems like this should be a really simple problem to solve. How can I assign an EventHandler to an object defined in a static method?

Comment: I'm currently at work, I'll edit and make an example when i'll get home ;)